# How to do validation for list of emails in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to email validation and for single emailid i am able to do that.

But i heard that my class will receive list of Emails from the application to validate.

I am not getting how to check bulk email validations.

```
 public class SmtpRequestContent
    {
        #region Declared smtp email variables

        [DataMember]
        public List<string> EmailTo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> EmailCC { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> EmailBCC { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String EmailSubject { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String EmailContent { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsBodyHtml { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<byte> Attachments { get; set; }

        #endregion

    }
```

I am  not confident about using list in C#, but i will get the above class object and i have to perform validation for all the email available in this object.

Kindly any body show me how to segregate the incoming list of mails, probably i think it will be in for loop.

I have to do all this validations in class library.

Thank you

Comment: a list of emails is the same as a `;` delimited string. you could do regex on that to validate, for instance.

Comment: how are you validating a single email address ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a method that validates a single email?  Just do:

```
foreach (SmtpRequestContent email in emails)
{
    YourValidateMethod(email);
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: understand, I will modify accordingly in emails, once done i will post here . Thank you

Comment: how i have to assign emails in the above foreach loop?

Comment: emails = whatever your list of emails is.  I don't know what context you're using this in.

Comment: public static bool IsEmailValid(SmtpGatewayRequest smtpRequest)
        {
           
            foreach (SmtpGatewayRequest email in smtpRequest.)
            {
                YourValidateMethod(email);
            }

            return true;
        }     do i need to pass IsEmailValid(SmtpGatewayRequest smtpRequest) list as a parameter in this?